# Android Material Design Bottom Bar and Webview

Tags: android, webview, material-design

I worked through this tutorial ([here](http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/)) to create a Bottom Bar. In this tutorial they explain how to change the text of the label, when changing the tab. But I want to have a webView that changes it's content when changing the tab.

Do you know a way to do that with the example given in the tutorial?

Thanks for your awnser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the piece of code that runs when you click on a button on the bottom bar:

```
    bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.three_buttons_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.recent_item:
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Recent Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.favorite_item:
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Favorite Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.location_item:
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

So just change the `Snackbar.make` calls with your code that change the content of your WebView.